# Is there a way to retrieve the legends from plotly or d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

In google charts, in order to get the selected legends, one can use the below snippet

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
       var sel = chart.getSelection();
       // sel contains all the selected legends 
    }
```

Is there any similar behavior in plotly? The intention behind this is, based on the legends, I have to derive different plots. For instance, if you select two legends, then I have to plot the relationship between those two variables. I have binded the plotly legend event, so whenever I click the legend name, the event gets triggered. Unfortunately, I couldn't retrieve any legend names.

> Or Is it possible to get selected legends in d3.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Using plotly's selectors I think something like this might help.

```
var graphDiv = document.getElementById('graph');
Plotly.plot(graphDiv, figure);
graphDiv.on('plotly_selected', function(selectedData) {
    // do something with selectedData
});
```

Comment: Thats only for the points you select on the graph. I want the similar behavior on selecting  legends

Comment: Right, I misunderstood. I think the best option would be to manage `plotly_legendclick` and `plotly_legenddoubleclick` events.